# Node.js API request loop without a memory overload

Tags: node.js, axios

This might seem strange but I'm trying to refresh an API as many times as possible until a `response.data` value reaches a certain number. Here's my code below

```
const axios = require('axios');
const api = require('./api.json');
const infinity = 0;

let url = 'http://api.site.com/api.php?i=${api[item].appid}';

function api_call(item){
  axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      let id = response.data.id;
      if (id > 10){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  function loop(variable) {
    while (infinity < 1) {
      if (api_call(variable) > true) {
        break;
        console.log('Found');
      }
      console.log('-');
    }
  }
```

This might seem strange, but obviously, I've modified it although this code would still achieve a similar goal to what I'm trying to accomplish with my code. Basically, it monitors an API until a value change triggers an action. Possibly I'm doing something wrong but when I run my version of this code (only changes are the API and value names) I start using massive amounts of Memory to the point that the program stops and gives me this error

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[11524:000001E5724778C0]    93390 ms: Mark-sweep 1395.2 (1426.2) -> 1394.5 (1425.7) MB, 629.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.139, current mu = 0.053) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[11524:000001E5724778C0]    94039 ms: Mark-sweep 1395.4 (1425.7) -> 1394.8 (1426.2) MB, 638.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.079, current mu = 0.016) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->
```

along with more information (if that's required I can edit the post and include it), I believe this is due to how I'm collecting the data, possibly there's some procedure I'm forgetting about I'm not so sure and can't find any similar topics regarding this. Thanks in advance for any help. If more information's required just ask I'll add more. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a little play around and this is what I ended up getting to work.

```
     const axios = require('axios');
     const api = require('./api.json');
     const infinity = 0;   

    function api_call(item) {
      let url = `http://api.site.com/api.php?i=${api[item].appid}`;
        axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      let id = response.data.id;
      if (id > 10){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

    async function checkAPI(variable) {
      const res = await api_call()

      if (res) {
        //success
      } else {
        //Fail
      }
    }

    checkAPI();
```